# VB.net SQL variable input value has no effect depending on position in select case statement - zeros output to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, variables, case-statement

I have setup a case statement below that looks at the student year (`stuyear`) (which will ultimately be triggered by an asp.net control. The case is set up to include this in the calculations when it outputs it's results to three columns. However, if I change the value of `stuyear` within `maindata` from 11 to 10 as below the output columns return 0s. The statement only appears to be effective for the first three cases then the last six it returns 0s as if they're being ignored.

What I want to happen is that when the `stuyear` changes the contents of `belowexpected`, `asexpected` and `aboveexpected`.

I don't want to setup separate columns for year 9, 10 and 11 and trigger their visibility in VB.net if it can be avoided.

You can find the specific code I'm referring to in the example below under the `/*Progress*/` comment.

```
;with MainData as 
(
select surname, forename, stuyear, ks2en, result, case when ks2en='' then 5 else left(ks2en,1) end as ks2enlevel, value as ResultLevel, case when ks2en='' then 0 else 1 end as gotks2enlevel 
from student join subject on student.upn=subject.upn join gradelookup on subject.result=gradelookup.grade where datacollection='March 2013' and stuyear=10 and name = 'English'
),

calcproglevel as
(
Select surname, forename, stuyear, ks2en, result, ks2enlevel, ResultLevel, gotks2enlevel, ResultLevel-ks2enlevel as levelsofprogress from MainData
),

calcprogtotals as
(
select surname, forename, stuyear, ks2en, result, ks2enlevel, ResultLevel, gotks2enlevel, levelsofprogress,
case when ks2enlevel >=4 then 1 else 0 end as AStarCTar,
case when resultlevel >=7 then 1 else 0 end as AStarC

From calcproglevel
)

select surname, forename, stuyear, ks2en, result, ks2enlevel, ResultLevel, gotks2enlevel, AStarCTar, AStarC, levelsofprogress, 

/*Progress*/

/*Year 11 Levels of Porgress below, as and above expected*/
case when stuyear=11 and levelsofprogress < 3 then 1 else 0 end as belowexpected,
case when stuyear=11 and levelsofprogress >= 3 then 1 else 0 end as asexpected,
case when stuyear=11 and levelsofprogress >= 4 then 1 else 0 end as aboveexpected,

/*Year 10 Levels of Porgress below, as and above expected*/
case when stuyear=10 and levelsofprogress < 2 then 1 else 0 end as belowexpected,
case when stuyear=10 and levelsofprogress >= 2 then 1 else 0 end as asexpected,
case when stuyear=10 and levelsofprogress >= 3 then 1 else 0 end as aboveexpected,

/*Year 9 Levels of Porgress below, as and above expected*/
case when stuyear=9 and levelsofprogress < 1 then 1 else 0 end as belowexpected,
case when stuyear=9 and levelsofprogress >= 1 then 1 else 0 end as asexpected,
case when stuyear=9 and levelsofprogress >= 2 then 1 else 0 end as aboveexpected,

/*KS4 individual levels of progress from 0 or less through to 5 levels or greater */
case when (stuyear=9 or stuyear=10 or stuyear=11) and levelsofprogress <= 0 then 1 else 0 end as zeroorless,
case when (stuyear=9 or stuyear=10 or stuyear=11) and levelsofprogress = 1 then 1 else 0 end as onelevelprog,
case when (stuyear=9 or stuyear=10 or stuyear=11) and levelsofprogress = 2 then 1 else 0 end as twolevelprog,
case when (stuyear=9 or stuyear=10 or stuyear=11) and levelsofprogress = 3 then 1 else 0 end as threelevelprog,
case when (stuyear=9 or stuyear=10 or stuyear=11) and levelsofprogress = 4 then 1 else 0 end as fourlevelprog,
case when (stuyear=9 or stuyear=10 or stuyear=11) and levelsofprogress >= 5 then 1 else 0 end as fiveormore


From calcprogtotals
```

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted it. Just required a rearrange and introducing or operators as below:

```
case when (stuyear=11 and levelsofprogress < 3)

or

(stuyear=10 and levelsofprogress < 2)

or

(stuyear=9 and levelsofprogress < 1)

then 1 else 0 end as belowexpected,
```